# How to integrate full screen RevMob Ads in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, revmob, revmobads

I want to integrate full screen RevMob Ad in and is able to add it but i some times get error that didRemoveListener nil value when i try it to click on ad to open it and close the add both at the same time.Please give any suggestions how to solve this issue.. thanks

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"    
local RevMob = require("revmob")
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local fullscreen
local revmobListener

local storyboard = require "storyboard"    
local REVMOB_IDS = { 
    ["Android"] = "",
    ["iPhone OS"] = ""
}

RevMob.startSession(REVMOB_IDS)
RevMob.setTestingMode(RevMob.TEST_WITH_ADS)

local function ShowAds()
    fullscreen.RevMob.createFullscreen()
    RevMob.showFullscreen(revmobListener, REVMOB_IDS)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two IDs **placement_ids** and **revmob_id**

The **revmob_id** is the App ID
https://console.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/mobile_apps

The **placement_id** is the ad unit in the created apps in the revmob

Try click an app in your **Apps** tab, then scroll down until you'll the **Ad Unit**

There should be a **Default** there, click the **Default** then you will be redirected to a new page, there should be an ID there. That's your **placement id** for that ad.

You can also Add a placement if you want and use the placement id of your created placement.

```
local PLACEMENT_IDS = {[REVMOB_ID_ANDROID] = "Your app id here", [REVMOB_ID_IOS] = "Your app id here"}

local function revmobListener(event)
    print("Event: " .. event.type .. " - " .. event.ad)
    if event.type == "adReceived" then
    elseif event.type == "adNotReceived" then
    elseif event.type == "adClicked" then
        revMobBanner = RevMob.createBanner({listener = revmobListener }, PLACEMENT_IDS)
    end
end

local REVMOB_IDS = { ["Android"] = "Your placement id here", ["iPhone OS"] = "Your placement id here" }
RevMob.startSession(REVMOB_IDS)

revMobBanner = RevMob.createBanner({listener = revmobListener }, PLACEMENT_IDS)
```